# Excel chart shows wrong data when zero-length string "" is in data

Tags: excel, plot, excel-charts

I am trying to make a scatter plot in Excel for Mac which should look like this:

[image]

I am using an IF formula which returns "" when my x-data is negative or 0 and then using this new column to make the plot. However, all the x-values in the plot turn out to be very different as here:

[image]

When I manually delete all the "" from the column, I get the correct plot. If I just add one "" in the column all the x-values change in the plot. I see the correct x-values in the spreadsheet column.

How can I get Excel to ignore the "" when plotting or plot the values that are shown? What is causing this error?

Comment: AFAIK, given your set-up, the only way to fix this is to have another place where you copy / paste the data as values and chart from that range because when using a formula Excel thinks there is *something* in the cell.

Comment: I have tried that already, but the cells with the "" also get pasted when I paste values. It appears blank but is still present since the plot is the same and if I delete the "" cells the plot appears correct.

Comment: Change your formula to return "X"`. Copy / paste and replace "X" with [nothing].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `""` with `NA()` in your IF formula to avoid plotting these values. Excel charts ignore #N/A cells. In your case, assuming your x-values are in column A, the formula in the new column (for plotting) is
`=IF(A2<=0,NA(),A2)`.

Comment: I use the new column later on to calculate averages. If I replace "" with NA()  then the average also returns NA().

Comment: @user2921731 `AVERAGEIF` formula can be used to ignore these NA() values when calculating averages: `=AVERAGEIF(B2:B1000,"<>#N/A")`